# What command does kubernetes run to launch a container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When I specify a Deployment in a kubernetes yaml file, for example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabel:
      deploy: example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deploy: example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          image: dockerhub.com/imagerepo:latest
```

I'm wondering what's going on in the backend to run my `deploy:example` pod. I'm guessing some sort of `docker run <image> && docker start <image>` command is executed on each node, but what exactly is the command?

Comment: Kubernets is written in GO and thats where you should start looking. 15 minutes of research will give you the answers ;)

Comment: What happens depends on the [container runtime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) used and this is not always docker. If you are interested in some history, check this post from May 2018: [Kubernetes Containerd Integration Goes GA](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/05/24/kubernetes-containerd-integration-goes-ga/)